# Updating a nested dictionary with multiple keys in the second dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

So, to preface this: I'm pretty new to coding & python so please forgive me if you look at this and wonder 'what was he thinking?'.

I'm working on my first real project outside tutorials, and I'm trying to create a workout planner, specifically 5/3/1. Which is a program that takes 90% of your one-rep-max, and delivers a program based on various percentages of that value.

What I'm working on / stuck on currently is creating a nested dictionary to represent the workouts across a month. There are 4 workouts in a month, and each workout has 3 sets. Each set is a percentage of the `self.training_max` value. All those values are stored in the `self.weights` list.

What I would like to end up with is a dictionary that looks like this: `{'Week 1': {'Set 1': 60, 'Set 2': 69, 'Set 3': 78}, 'Week 2': {'Set 1': 'Set 1': 64, 'Set 2': 74, 'Set 3': 83}}` etc.

If you run it you'll see I'm so close but there is something wrong with how I'm having the `.create_workout()` method update the dictionary. I added print statements to help me keep track of the recursion, and the correct values are being called at the correct time but when they are added to the dictionary they are added as every single value of the parent dictionary.

So by the end the sets for all four weeks are given the same values as they're being overridden each time `change_value()` is called.

What am I missing? I'm also hugely open for any other feedback on anything you see also as, like I said, I'm still very new to this.

```
import math 

class exercise:

def __init__(self, name, reps, weight, unit='kg', weeks=4, sets=3):
    self.name = name.title()
    self.reps = reps
    self.weight = weight
    self.one_rep = math.floor(self.weight * (1 + (self.reps / 30)))
    self.training_max = math.floor(self.one_rep * .90)
    self.unit = unit
    self.percentages = [.65, .75, .85, .70, .80, .90, .75, .85, .95, .40, .50, .60]
    self.weights = [round (percentage * self.training_max) for percentage in self.percentages]
    self.weeks_list = ['Week ' + str(week + 1) for week in range(weeks)]
    self.sets_dict = {"Set " + str(set + 1): 0 for set in range(sets)}
    self.workout_dict = {week: self.sets_dict for week in self.weeks_list}

def create_workout_2(self):
    def change_val(dictionary_this, i_this):
        for key, weight in zip(dictionary_this.keys(), self.weights[i_this: i_this + 3]):
            print (f'Key = {key}. Weight = {weight}')
            dictionary_this[key] = weight

        return dictionary_this
    i = -3
    for week in self.workout_dict.keys():
        i+= 3
        print (f'\nFor loop: This is {week}, i_this is {i}, weights are {self.weights[i : i + 3]}, they key being used is {week}')
        self.workout_dict[week] = change_val(self.workout_dict[week], i)
        print (f'The values for {week} are {self.workout_dict[week]}')

    return self.workout_dict

squat_workout = squat.create_workout_2()
print (f'\nsquat.weights = {squat.weights}')
print (f'\nFinal squat_workout output= {squat_workout}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using the same `self.sets_dict` for every week. Thus, when you update the program for different weeks, the changes are applied to *all* weeks. You need to make sure that you have a unique `sets_dict` per week.

Instead of re-using the same dict, make a copy of it for each week. To make a copy, you can either import the `copy` module and use `copy.copy` (in some cases, not this, though, you should instead use `copy.deepcopy`). However, another way to get a shallow copy (i.e. `copy.copy`) is to pass the data structure to its constructor. Doing this, removes the reqiurement to add `import copy` to your file. It is less general, but when possible, I find it clearer.

Thus, all you have to do is to change

```
        self.workout_dict = {week: self.sets_dict for week in self.weeks_list}
```

to

```
        self.workout_dict = {week: dict(self.sets_dict) for week in self.weeks_list}
```

and the code will work as you intend. I would like to add one more thing, though. There is no requirement to declare all variables used in a method of a class as `self...` Only variables that needs to be remembered between methods. In your case there is no need to use `self.percentages, self.week_list, self.sets_dict`. It would be better to just use `percentages, weeks_list, sets_dict` without `self.` (`sets_dict` might seem like you need to keep, but (copies of) it is already stored in the `self.workout_dict` so no direct access is needed.)

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it! I didn't have to import copy, I just added 'dict' to the dictionary comprehension and it did it. 

I also made the changes you suggested about not using self. I understand what you mean there, thanks. That's helpful!